# Restrict case clients to organizations?

Tags: civicase

Is there a way i could restrict case clients to organizations only when creating a new case?

Wouldn't necessarily need to only show orgs in the autocomplete search, as long as submitting was restricted to orgs only..

I'm using Drupal 7 and latest CiviCRM

Thanks!

Comment: You could do this via Webforms if you are using Drupal so it is worth mentioning the CMS being used.

Answer (score 1):

You should check what the webform_civicrm module offers as it allows for Cases to be created, and in theory if you set the Contact on the webform to be restricted to Organisation, then you may get the outcome you require.

If not, please expand on your question with more specific requirements